DateTimePickerModal dont show time when set mode datetime on IOS
I am using mode="datetime" and display="inline", but the time selector is not showing.
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isDatetimePickerVisible}
        mode="datetime"
        onConfirm={handleConfirmDate}
        onCancel={hideDatePicker}
        display="inline"
        confirmTextIOS="Confirm"
        cancelTextIOS="Cancel"
      />

    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "axios": "^1.7.4",
    "expo": "~51.0.26",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.21",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "npm": "^10.8.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^18.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "swr": "^2.2.5",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"

Problem image
I tried using only @react-native-community/datetimepicker, and it works. I want to use this with DateTimePickerModal.

Time section is located under the calendar. You need to scroll down a little bit to see the time section.

This modal is at the bottom, and I can't scroll down any further.

Seems like it is a bug in styling, please see the issue in github.
